# Javascript delete a table tbody tag

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I know I can use the following code to remove rows in vanilla Javascript:

```js
var table = document.getElementById('table');
    
function deleteRow () {
  table.deleteRow(1);
};
```

```css
table { background: #ccc; width: 100%; }
table thead { background: #333; color: #fff; }
table tbody { background: magenta; color: #fff; }
```

```html
<button onclick="deleteRow()">Delete Row</button>
<table id="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>foo</td>
        <td>bar</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>lorem</td>
          <td>ipsum</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>lorem</td>
          <td>ipsum</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

But this code leaves an empty tbody tag behing. JS has methods for removing thead and tfoot elements, but it seems it's missing a `deleteTbody` one.

How am I supposed to remove a `tbody` and all it's contents by using pure javascript only? No jQuery, please!

Comment: You can remove tbody contents, but not the tbody itself, it doesn't make sense. What's your objetive? Why you need a table if you want to remove the tbody?

Comment: @RandallValenciano I need to remove all the child rows inside the tbody element in one move, without using an iterator, so it makes sense to simply remove the tbody. This table renders the result of a server request that happens every 10 minutes and I need to remove the previous items, but the <thead> must remain untouched.

Comment: All the answers miss that the HTMLTableElement has a tBodies property which can be used, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove the `tbody` tag, you could select the row itself rather than the table, then use the `removeChild` function.

```
var table = document.getElementById('table');
var row = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];


function deleteRow () {
    row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
};
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `table.getElementsByTagName`?

Answer (score 11):

Try using:

```
var tbl = document.getElementById("table"); // Get the table
tbl.removeChild(tbl.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0]); // Remove first instance of body
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Ltdr2qv4/1/

Comment: thanks for removing the useless effort suggested by answer

Answer (score 3):

Use [**`querySelectorAll()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to iterate through all `TBODY` elements, then remove those that have no children:

```js
var table = document.getElementById('table');

function deleteRow() {
  table.deleteRow(1);

  var tb = document.querySelectorAll('tbody');
  for (var i = 0; i < tb.length; i++) {
    if (tb[i].children.length === 0) {
      tb[i].parentNode.removeChild(tb[i]);
    }
  }
};
```

```css
table {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
}
table thead {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
table tbody {
  background: magenta;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="deleteRow()">Delete Row</button>
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>foo</td>
      <td>bar</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>lorem</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>lorem</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The HTMLTableElement has a tBodies property with a remove() method:

```
var table = document.getElementById('table');
table.tBodies[0].remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `deleteTbody` but there is `removeChild`:

```
var parent = document.getElementById("parent-id");
var child = document.getElementById("child-id");
parent.removeChild(child);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help you. I am sorry. It is too late to answer.

tbody-data is tbody's id value.

```
$("#tbody-data tr").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function deleteRow() {
    var rows = document.getElementById("table").rows.length;
    for (j = 1; j < rows; j++){
        document.getElementById("table").deleteRow(1);
    }
}
```